# Autoscaling On-Demand HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure-data-factory, autoscaling, azure-hdinsight

Is there a way to enable autoscaling in an on-demand cluster created in Azure Data Factory?
The CPU usage sometimes exceeds expectations.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, Autoscaling option is not available for on-demand HDInsight clusters. And It's only available on [Azure HDInsight clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-autoscale-clusters).

You can create a on-demand HDInsight cluster with the predefined cluster size.

In this type of configuration, the computing environment is fully managed by the Azure Data Factory service. It is automatically created by the Data Factory service before a job is submitted to process data and removed when the job is completed. You can create a linked service for the on-demand compute environment, configure it, and control granular settings for job execution, cluster management, and bootstrapping actions.

For more details, refer [Azure HDInsight on-demand linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compute-linked-services#azure-hdinsight-on-demand-linked-service).

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217335-hdinsight

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.